# How do I retrieve credential passed by user in soap wsdl Java Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am sending my credentials using,

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password".toCharArray());
            }
});
```

My question is now how can I retrieve this credentials in Soap webservice Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution,

```
ArrayList<String> authList = (ArrayList<String>) http_headers.get("Authorization");
```

It returns Credentials in Base64.